# Buscar palavras e tratar o resultado em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo resultado nesse código com mais de uma palavra para busca alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
(function() {
    var words = ["palavra1","palavra2","palavra3"];
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
            if (newNodes !== null) {

                var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.WebComment');
                for (var i = 0, nn = nodes.length; i < nn; i++)
                {
                    var text = nodes[i] ? nodes[i].textContent.toLowerCase() : '';
                    if (text && text.indexOf(words[i]) >= 0 && nodes[i].style.display != 'none')
                    {
                        nodes[i].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro somente com código do que pretende fazer @VictoriaSouza. Poderia fornecer alguma explicação adicional?

Comment: @LucasCosta seria uma extensão que buscaria palavras x entre os comentários da página e esconderia eles. como se fosse um "filtro"